# How to run specific test using using gradlew on command line?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit, gradle

I'm quite new with the Android gradle build.
I built and application and it work quite ok. Now I would like to add unit test and instrument test into it, and execute them on command line.

I have to test files:

- `MainActivityTest.java`  <== This used instrumentation test which should be executed on a device.
- `CustomerFragmentTest.java` <== This used junit test which should be executed on JVM only.

Now from the command line in `Project Directory` I called

`gradlew test --continue`

And it executed all tests (both JVM tests and Device Tests) while I expect only the JVM tests to be run.

So:

> 1. How can I run the junit test cases on JVM only (Ignore the instrumentation test cases)?
> 2. When I call `gradlew connectedCheck` I got the execution failed message:
>
>    *"Task 'connectedCheck' not found in root project'Android5Camera'"*
>
>    How can I execute the instrumentation tests
>      (on Device) using command line?

Thank for any help and advice.

Here by my app.gradle config in case you need:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.huynhle.android5camera"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        main.setRoot('src/main')
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can assume, you have put both class-files to the same directory **src/test**. This directory is appropriate only for unit tests, and test runner don't distinguish test files between Intsrumentation or simple JUnit. That's why the `gradlew test --continue` command launches both classes.
Android Instrumentation Tests classes should be located in the **src/androidTest** directory and should be heirs (direct or no) of InstrumentationTestCase or AndroidTestCase, then you can launch instrumentation tests using `gradlew connectedCheck`.